# Drawing line chart without lower and upper bound in c#

Tags: c#, charts

For example, I added xy points in Series1 with this code.

```
   //mock graph
   chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
   for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
   {
       chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, i);
   }
   chart1.Invalidate();
```

In short, my code adds 9 points from x=1 to x=9.
Problem is the graph also shows x=0 and x=10 which I don't want.
Anyone know how to fix this?
[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it myself. For anyone who has same problem.

In properties,
select **ChartAreas**,
select **Axes**.
In **Scale**, set **IsMarginVisible** to false.

[image]

Comment: You should accept your answer, so the question won't look unresolved!